# encoding and decoding of audio files to send over the internet to decrease size. android

Tags: android, audio, encoding, compression, decoding

i am making an android app in which we transfer audio files over the internet . But as the file size is large we need to encode and decode mp3 and other formats which we are unable to find a way till now .Like whatsapp they decreasses the size by appreciable amount . Can u help me and tell us a better way to encode and decode in android
and i want to do similar things in php website . Please guide me .

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding of your question, CODEC is what exactly you need to use.
 
**[CODEC](http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/multimedia/f/codec.htm)** is actually a piece of code or a program that compresses data to enable faster transmission and decompresses received data.
Since your application will be dealing with the transfer of audio files, you can go for [Audio codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_codecs) or if any other rich media you want, accordingly you can choose the suitable one.

And even for different audio formats to be supported and their conversion, [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) is what you can refer, also to the [formats](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html) and [codecs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html). 
To decide which codec to use and which not,refer [here](http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/multimedia/f/codec.htm).

Hope it helps and you can further ask for assistance needed in any case.

Comment: using ffmpeg is making the app quite heavy which is why i am searching for alternative. i have downloaded ffmpeg codec from som place and that increased my app size by 8 mb. which is not good too.